# images 404'ing in sonarqube review feedback

Tags: sonarqube

Getting broken images for all images in SonarQube analysis (in GitHub). Clicking on any of them shows they 404 out.

[image]

Maybe there's something we should do in our GitHub account? Or something SonarQube should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they renamed the Github project from SonarCommunity to SonarSource https://github.com/SonarSource

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-github/master/images/severity-major.png

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SonarSource/sonar-github/master/images/severity-major.png

I think you (we  ) probably need to update our version of the plugin
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-github/pull/32

Comment: FYI fix has been released in version 1.4.1 : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin